# How do I backup my mac with Optimize Mac Storage

Tags: icloud, backup

How can I backup my Mac when I have Optimize Mac Storage turned on?

Backblaze, Arq, and CCC all won't follow the offline file links. But I want a complete copy of my Mac backed up. The iCloud copy isn't sufficient. (iCloud protects against hardware failure, not accidental deletion.)

Comment: Forgive the obvious question, but is there a reason you don't want to use Time Machine? If so you should [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/346936/edit) your question to clarify your requirements.

Comment: I don't think TM will backup those dummy files. You can restore accidental deleted files on icloud.com website. Nevertheless it can't be as reliable as local backups. iCloud Drive is poor in many aspects.

Comment: Good catch. I gave up on Time Machine when Apple stopped making the Time Capsule. I've tried to find a NAS solution that actually works but I haven't. And @amdyes is correct, TM doesn't back up the dummy files.